# Windows 10 keeps freezing, but the CPU and Disk usage drops

Tags: windows-10, freeze

Recently, this started happening randomly. Programs would stop responding, but task manager shows abnormally low CPU and Disk activity.
Sometimes it unfreezes on its own after about half an hour, but mostly I had to hard reboot the laptop.
The same type of errors showed up in Event Viewers when this happens, the latest of which I'd saved the system log for, right here:
[Download from dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/shsl06j39ihv4og/20160308FR%201255.evtx?dl=0)

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be relevant, but recently I had these symptoms and it turned out that the version of Classic Shell that replaces the Windows 10 Start button was causing the problems. I uninstalled Classic shell and got used to Windows 10 start.

Maybe you are running some other extension , say an extension to Windows Explorer, that is holding some kind of "resource lock" at a high priority and blocking other processes without consuming CPU or memory? The symptom would be the system was very sluggish but CPU and Memory utilisation were low.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the task manager, not only the cpu usage but the memory and disk usage as well, if any of those are filling up, that would be causing the problem, knowing which would help diagnose further

Comment: I kept the task manager open all the time as a matter of habit, and I can tell you that when the freeze happens, everything (CPU, disk usage, memory) show curiously low activity, even while the programs stopped responding. Can't even shut them down from the task manager either. Nor can I start up any new programs.